# Cannot connect to a MySQL database from a C++ program with MySQL Connector/C++: exception thrown

Tags: c++, mysql, exception, database-connection, mysql-connector

I have a connection problem to a MySQL database from a C++ program:

```
std::string server, user, password;
SetParams(server, user, password);
boost::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> conn;
sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();

if(driver == 0) { /* error; never reached */ }

try {
    conn.reset(driver->connect(server, user, password));

    assert(conn != 0);

    if(!conn->isClosed())    // <-- exception thrown
    {
        // Connection established
    }
    else {
        // Connection failed
    }
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e)
{
    cerr << e.what << e.getErrorCode() << e.getSQLState() << endl;
}
```

The `sql::Connection::isClosed()` function throws this exception:

```
SQLException: Connection has been closed  
MySQL error code: 0  
SQLState: HY000
```

The values for server, user and password are correct (they work connecting from MySQL-Workbench), the DB is up and running.

I do not know where else to look...
Thank you.

Platform:
Linux - OpenSuse 11.4
MySQL 5.x
MySQL Connector/C++ 1.0.5

---

Update:
Since I read somewhere about possible conflicts between MySQL Connector/C++ and Boost, I tried to use a plain pointer instead of a boost::shared_ptr. Nothing changed.

---

Update 2:
Isolating this code out of the main program, the connection is done successfully.
I must look at the bigger picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting and pasting the code to access the database in a new test project, everything works fine.
No exception is generated and the connection is established.

This means I have to look at what happens in the rest of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not work for me. Switching to a new project or even creating a separate function that handles connection did not help. I have added more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619633/unexpected-error-on-connecting-to-mysql-database-using-c-connector).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html#test

The problem is it with the connection that you are creating with the db

```
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    /* create a database connection using the Driver */
    con = driver -> connect(url, user, password);
    /* alternate syntax using auto_ptr to create the db connection */
    //auto_ptr  con (driver -> connect(url, user, password));
    /* turn off the autocommit */
    con -> setAutoCommit(0);
    cout << "\nDatabase connection\'s autocommit mode = " << con -> getAutoCommit() << endl;
    /* select appropriate database schema */
    con -> setSchema(database);
```

Comment: Considering that in my code I call the `setAutoCommit()` and `setSchema()`  functions in the "// Connection established" block, the only difference is in my `conn.reset(driver->connect(...));` vs your direct assignment. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes you are correct those are the secondary things main was the `conn.reset(driver->connect(...));' try changing that connection statement.

Comment: I use `reset()` because I am using a shared pointer. It is an assignment.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to use plain pointers instead of `boost::shared_ptr` or `auto_ptr` (as MySQL does)?